# Issue Writing to external storage

Tags: android

I'm working from this tutorial of how to add camera functionality in my app and save the photos taken.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

With this version I can not find the photo's after when saving using

```
getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

The camera works but the pictures are nowhere to be found after.

I have tried to use

```
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
```

However with this the camera does not even load.

Any advice on why this may be happening would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You and Camera both can not use the Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM at the same time. So when you are trying to access the same and then try to use camera as well, then at that time Camera also tries to access Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM which is already acquired by you. Hence Camera does not work for that time.

To implement the Camera in your app:

```
Intent e = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
Uri mImageCaptureUri = your required file path's URI;
e.putExtra("output", mImageCaptureUri);
e.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(e, 1);
```

Now use onActivityResult method to access the captured image.

Comment: That makes sense - in which case do you know why getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); won't save images and how I might be able to?

Comment: @Nowandthen98 Please refer the edited answer and now you don't need to use Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below direction to save your files in the internal storage

```
 String PicDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
```

then you will find your save files in the below path
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/*your package name* /files/Pictures/

Comment: Still does not work as the camera won't open when I attempt to use ExternalStoragePublicDirectory